# Arrange words to get max height

Tags: algorithm, math, text

In my app I have a frame inside which user can form a "sentence" from random source words. I should calculate words font size so they will fit this frame (any order, any number - even all - of words can be used).

Words are placed one-by-one from top-left corner. If next word exceeds frame width - it's moved to a new line. So result words height shouldn't exceed frame's one. To simplify algorithm let's ignore paddings (between words, lines). All words have same height and font.

Can't find anything better than NP-completeness... Any ideas?

*UPDATE:*

This question is: "How can I calculate words maximum height?" Problem: this height depends on words order.

*UPDATE2:*

Exact question by @Teepeemm: "What arrangement of the words will need the most lines to display?"

Comment: This sounds perfect for a binary search. But otherwise if you just iterated through font sizes from 10 to 50 that would be O(n) so I don't understand why this is NP complete.

Comment: @AlexHall, updated the question.

Comment: Is this just about the _height_ of the font, or the _size_, i.e. height _and_ width? If only height: Arrange the word so they fit on the fewest lines and then stretch the height until those lines fill the entire frame. Also, it would really help if you posted some image of how you expect the result to look.

Comment: @tobias_k I think the question is "what arrangement of the words will need the most lines to display."

Comment: @Teepeemm No, for different font sizes there will be different arrangements. Question is (seems to be): find such order of words and font size N so that any other word order in size N doesn't have more lines and these words don't fit in frame with font size N+1. Font can be limited by width as well (say, if we have only one long word).

Comment: @Abstraction if I can answer Teepeemm's question, I can answer yours (simply by checking different font sizes with preferred search algorithm). So his question is "the only problem" inside whole task.

Comment: @kpower Well, it's *one* way to get the answer: get estimate for given font, then determine number of lines (which corresponds to some interval of fonts), then determine the font. But precise answer in this approach so far *seems* to be NP-complete task (there's an easy estimate for number of lines L which leaves a gap of (width of frame + width of (L-1) longest words)). Still don't have strict proof, though.